# Excel VBA Formula variable find data not working

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am applying following formula via vba and it throws error.

```
Cells(MyRow1 + 4, 3).Formula = "=RIGHT(" & Cells(MyRow1 + 2, 2).Address & ",LEN(" & Cells(MyRow1 + 2, 2).Address & ")-FIND(" & Cells(MyRow1 + 3, 3) & "," & Cells(MyRow1 + 2, 2).Address & ")-2)"
```

The output I get in the cell is

```
=RIGHT($B$31,LEN($B$31)-FIND(CA,$B$31)-2)
```

If I apply "" in Find function, it works:

```
=RIGHT($B$31,LEN($B$31)-FIND("CA",$B$31)-2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the extra `"` i use the `Chr(34)`.

change your `Formula` to:

```
Cells(MyRow1 + 4, 3).Formula = "=RIGHT(" & Cells(MyRow1 + 2, 2).Address & _
                            ",LEN(" & Cells(MyRow1 + 2, 2).Address & ")-FIND(" & Chr(34) & _
                            Cells(MyRow1 + 3, 3) & Chr(34) & "," & Cells(MyRow1 + 2, 2).Address & ")-2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with this formula, but if you want to include the quotations in the output to the cell you can simply escape them, by using double-quotations.

```
... FIND(""" & Cells(MyRow1 + 3, 3) & """," & ...
```